# conditional php help

Tags: php, magento

How can I wrap this entire statement below in a condition? So If the variable $uprice = 0 then I don't want to to display any of the code below

```
   <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item-  >getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>

   <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>

  <?php else: ?>
  <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item-    >getCalculationPrice()) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This??

```
<?php if ($uprice === 0): ?>    
     <?php if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item-  >getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()): ?>    
     <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition()); ?>    
     <?php else: ?>
     <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item-    >getCalculationPrice()) ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($uprice == 0){
  if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') 
      && $_item-  >getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount())
  {
    echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()
      +$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition());
  } else {
    echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code would be more readable by containing it all in one php block, and as Sarfraz said shouldn't it be as simple as adding a condition around the stuff?

```
<?php 
if ($uprice == 0)
{
    if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_item, array(0, 1, 4), 'sales') && $_item-  >getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount())
    {
        echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item->getCalculationPrice()+$_item->getWeeeTaxAppliedAmount()+$_item->getWeeeTaxDisposition());
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_item-    >getCalculationPrice());
    }
}
?>
```